codename one ios error build after migrate to xcode 15
We are encountering iOS build errors in our projects after the update; we haven't made any modifications to the source code, but recently we've been getting this error:
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /var/folders/qb/8bn8h7993fq_r1xc549w05yw0000gn/T/build4270225424440926984xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJET_NAME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PROJET_NAME.build/Release-iphoneos/PROJET_NAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/OpenUDID.o /var/folders/qb/8bn8h7993fq_r1xc549w05yw0000gn/T/build4270225424440926984xxx/dist/PROJET_NAME-src/OpenUDID.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'PROJET_NAME' from project 'PROJET_NAME')
Thank you for noting the urgency of the request. We are planning an emergency production rollout.
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /var/folders/qb/8bn8h7993fq_r1xc549w05yw0000gn/T/build4270225424440926984xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJET_NAME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PROJET_NAME.build/Release-iphoneos/PROJET_NAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/OpenUDID.o /var/folders/qb/8bn8h7993fq_r1xc549w05yw0000gn/T/build4270225424440926984xxx/dist/PROJET_NAME-src/OpenUDID.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'PROJET_NAME' from project 'PROJET_NAME')

This was fixed last night probably around when this was posted. Make sure you're using the latest update.
